# How to know UI automation client is listening to my WPF app

Tags: wpf, ui-automation, screen-readers

I want to make my app to be accessible (make my app exposed for screen readers, which are UI automation client, like "`Narrator`").

I got some `ContentControl` that when it got keyboard focus, I'm showing a tooltip (taking it from the `Tooltip` property of this `ContentControl`). It's a control that used in many ways, for example it can be used like that: 
the `Content` of this `ContentControl` is a question mark icon image, and the `ToolTip` is the help text...

Here is a concept code:

```
class AutoTooltipOnFocus : ContentControl
{
    public AutoTooltipOnFocus()
    {
        this.GotKeyboardFocus += OnGotKeyboardFocus;
    }

    private void OnGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs keyboardFocusChangedEventArgs)
    {
        bool automationListens = AutomationPeer.ListenerExists(AutomationEvents.AutomationFocusChanged);

        if (automationListens)
        {
            // don't show tooltip because GetNameCore of MyAutoPeer will represent the ToolTip value
            return;
        }

        // show tooltip (by reading the ToolTip value of this AutoTooltipOnFocus)
    }

    protected override AutomationPeer OnCreateAutomationPeer()
    {
        return new MyAutoPeer(this);
    }
}

class MyAutoPeer : FrameworkElementAutomationPeer
{
    private AutoTooltipOnFocus _owner;

    public MyAutoPeer(AutoTooltipOnFocus owner)
        : base(owner)
    {

    }

    protected override string GetNameCore()
    {
        return GetToolTipValueFromOwner();
    }

    private string GetToolTipValueFromOwner()
    {
        // just for the simplicity of the example, I return this:
        return ToolTipService.GetToolTip(_owner).ToString();
    }
}
```

`Narrator`, for example, reads the textual representation of the `Content` (let's say the property `AutomationProperties.Name` of the image is set to "help icon") and then says "Tooltip: some help text".

I don't want to count on the tooltip been read by all the screen readers (correct me if I'm wrong thinking some of them don't read Tooltips), so I made my `GetNameCore` return the `ToolTip` content so that I know it would be read necessarily, and I prevented the appearance of the tooltip (at `OnGotKeyboardFocus` handler) in order to prevent double reading of the same help text.

The problem is that: I thought that asking `AutomationPeer.ListenerExists(AutomationEvents.AutomationFocusChanged)` tells me that UI automation is listening to my app, but when narrator is not running, this method returns "false" and the rest of the times it returns true, so no tooltip appears when no one using screen reader, so I need to know what is the way to indicate whether UI automation client is running and listening to my app.
Maybe there is a workaround by adding some code to my custom `AutomationPeer`.

Thanks for giving your time!

Comment: but when narrator is not running, this method returns "false" and the rest of the times it returns true -- isn't that what you're expecting?

Comment: when the narrator is not running, I want to show the tooltip, because it means the user that using my app currently can read and doesn't have eye problems. If I'll prevent from the tooltip to appear, the "normal" user won't know what that icon means when focused on the icon by keyboard.

Comment: I got your problem...but you stated that AutomationPeer.ListenerExists returns false when narrator is not running and true all the other times..then what is wrong with this?

Comment: I can't count on it, I need this question to return false always. each keyboard focus this question is asked. I can't show one tooltip and then no tooltips for the rest of the use.